# What could cause this pyomo error: "ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value"?

Tags: pyomo

Very occasionally I get this error when running pyomo: "ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: 0.0". It looks a little like the error that results when some solvers return, for example, 0.0 instead of 0 and this then leads to an error when re-using the results with the, for example, within=Binary keyword argument of the Var function. I don't believe this is the case here. Can anyone give me some ideas as to what may cause this error? I was using glpk at the time.

Here's some more info. I'm solving an optimisation problem sequentially, a day at a time. So the solution from yesterday becomes an input to today's problem. Here are some simplified code spinets:

```
results = manager.solve(instance, kwargs...)
instance.solutions.load_from(results)
states_dict = get_next_states(instance, time, args...)

def get_next_states(instance, time, args...):
    states_dict = {}
    for state in states:
        var = getattr(instance, state)
        for a in a_list:
            value = var[a, time].value
            states_dict[state, a] = force_domain(value, integer, tolerance)
    return states_dict
```

force_domain forces value to be integer and/or nonnegative, depending on the integer and tolerance arguments. The code fails when evaluating force_domain; sometimes with the above error, and sometimes with a TypeError exception: TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < int(). Here's force_domain:

```
def force_domain(x, integer, nonnegative):
    y = x
    if x < 0 and nonnegative:
        y = chop_tiny(y, nonnegative)
    if integer:
        y = round_if_int(y)
    return y

def chop_tiny(x, tol):
    if abs(x) > tol or isinstance(x, int):
        return x
    else:
        return 0.0

def round_if_int(x):
    if isinstance(x, float) and (x).is_integer():
        return int(x)
    else:
        return x
```

These errors occur in less than 1 in 2000 runs.

Does this extra info help you to answer my question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please provide the code as it will prove helpful in answering the question. I suggest reading [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).  Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Yes, please show some code so that we can give you a more informed response.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to isolate and reproduce the error. It turns out to be due to numerical instability in GLPK v4.57 that resulted in a crash. This numerical instability appears to have been fixed in GLPK v4.60. See https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2016-04/msg00000.html.